Handling local notifications actions on the background
I'm creating an app that plays some audio files with positive affirmations, and I have a feature on my app to get a notification to remind users to play an affirmation daily.
I'm able to create the notification and to handle when users click on the notifications but I'm having trouble handling when they click on a 'Play' action inside the notification.
I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications to schedule notifications and https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background to play files.
I implemented a handler to receive notification actions on the background as described in  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#notification-actions.
When I receive an event on 'onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse' this is received on a background isolate, I have a Riverpod provider to play audio on the background but it seems that I can't access it because my main function has not been called and the provider has not been created. How should I handle cases like this one, when the notification handler is in a background handler but I need stuff from my main isolate?

I managed to solve this myself, I had to create a new riverpod provider Container  inside my background notification handler, since I don't have access to the one created in the min function. Something like:
var providerContainer = ProviderContainer(); // This is the key part
var audioPlayer = providerContainer.read(audioPlayerProvider);
  ....

Hope this helps someone in the future
